# Half Duplex RS-485 to Modbus communication

Tags: rs485

I am having trouble to determine how to wire up my RS485 half duplex to a Digi One IAP from an Atlas Copco Modbus Gateway.

From Atlas Copco, the gateway needs is setup to use RS-485 Half duplex, no echo. The pin out seems different from a standard DB9 from what i googled. See image below for the gateway DB9 pin layout.

[image]

Here is the Digi One IAP layout. I am using the screw terminals for this.

[image]

The way i am thinking it should be hooked up is my as follow

Gateway    DigiOne

3----------7

8----------6

or would i send it this way like a RS232?

Gateway    DigiOne

3----------3

8----------6

Let me know if you need anymore clarifications

Thank you

Comment: RS-232 is not compatible with RS-485 so why do you think it would work? And when you wire it as RS-485 why do you swap the data polarity? And RS-485 does not work without a common ground reference, so is there a reason to omit ground?

Comment: You need a level-converter to properly convert between RS485 & RS232, and since your RS485 is half duplex you also need some sort of direction control. Just wiringt hem together like that won't work.

Comment: @Justme I was thinking i would wire the digi one in a similar fashion as RS232 but still use the RS485 for the dip switches. For the common ground reference, i just didn't show it on the diagram because i didn't have any confusion on it. Thank you for replying!

Comment: @brhans i will not be using RS232, i wondering if i wired it up in the similar fashion. But i think with yours, Justme and nasah1 comments, i think i figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excerpt from the [Digi One IAP quick start guide](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/DigiDocs/pdfs/90000634-88.pdf):

[image]

It describes the pin out of the device in half duplex mode. Normally RS-485 half duplex is a 2 wire bus (+ gnd) so you will need to bridge the RxD+/TxD+ and RxD-/TxD- lines on the Digi One side as described [here](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000YGwxCAG&l=en-US).

This results in the following wiring:
[image]